# How to return count of updated rows in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a SQL "Update" query and on which I am updating the matching records by Inner JOin of temporary table. Please check the query below-

```
update tblProduct as p
inner join #temp_Product prod on p.id = prod.id and p.name = prod.name
```

Now I want to return a table which will contain the columns "id", "name" and the count of updated rows (of tblProduct table) on the basis of "id" and "name".

Please check the tables below-

**1) tblProduct**

[image]

**2) #temp_Product**

[image]

**3) And below result should return**

[image]

Comment: Might I suggest you take a moment and edit your post to use text instead of images, and if you must use images, remove the unnecessary white space. Also, show what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Can you be clearer on if you want to run a query on the two tables or you want to update tblProduct? The tblProduct and the result table you showed have different columns set.

Comment: Use the `OUTPUT` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your database and what you use to access it, you might be able to get a summary count of total updated rows directly from the `update` statement, but since you want more detail it's unlikely you can use built-in database support.

What I would do is run a separate select query - probably *before* the update, but in the same transaction if possible - that will count the updates to be applied.

Since you didn't provide the `SET` expressions I can't include checking that a change would actually be made, but that shouldn't be hard to add to the query (just add `where` conditions for `<oldValue> != <newValue>`); the ability to do this is why you'd run the `select` before the `update`.

Basic query is:

```
select p.id, p.name, count(*)
  from            tblProduct as p
       inner join #temp_Product prod 
               on p.id = prod.id 
              and p.name = prod.name
 group by p.id, p.name
```